# Opening a PDF in new tab - Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I can't figure this one out.  I'm creating a PDF file upload form.  Very simple.

To view the PDF the user uploaded, I created a link to it with `target='_blank'`.

However when I click the link, I get the source of the PDF.  No matter how much I refresh, I get the source.  There is no errors with the upload, the file is there.  If I log in via FTP and download the uploaded file, the file is complete and opens on my machine perfectly.

If I copy the link from the newly opened tab, and paste it in a new tab, I get the proper PDF.  What the hell is going on?

Comment: Can you add the code to the question please

Comment: What code? A href?

Comment: The Anchor in full